# What's the better way to display an error message in PHP?

Tags: php

I have created three php forms. The first one(form.php) contains the form tag, the second one(form1.php)
is where the information goes. The last one(formerror.php), I have created when I couldn't find a way to
display an error message on the first page(form.php). What I want to know is, is it appropriate to do so?
- create the exact same page as the first just in order to display the error message.

[image]

this is the first page.

[image]

And this is the last page that I had to copy exactly the first page in order to display the error message.

the first page has a form from which I enter info and send them in the second page which is form1.php

```
    CODE FROM THE FIRST PAGE(form.php):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        form {
            border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            width: 19%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(5,25,9,0.2);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
//This is the form from form.php
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
        <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Enter password again">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </form>
    
    <p style="color: red;" class="erreur"></p>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    //This is the second page
```

Once informations entered from form.php, the come here and get displayed because we have given the username and the email address
CODE FROM THE SECOND PAGE(form1.php):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>FORM 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $submit_btn = $_POST['submit_btn'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
    
        if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
            if ((empty($_POST['username'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['password'])) || (empty($_POST['cpassword']))) {
                // header("Location:form.php");
                header("Location:formerror.php");
            }else{
                echo "Welcome $username, your email address is $email";
            }
        }
    
    ?>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is the page that I had to create in order to display an error. What I did is, I copied the exact same page as form.php but at the bottom, I added a message as you can see in the picture.

```
    AND CODE FROM THE THIRD PAGE(formerror.php): 
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                display: block;
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            form {
                border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                width: 19%;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: rgba(5,25,9,0.2);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
        <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Enter password again">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </form>
    
    <p style="color: red;">Please fill the form</p>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, the pages are there.And I would also like to know if my codes are well done although they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can work it out by using one file only. Send your form data to the same page.
Add your PHP script before at the beginning of your file like this.

```
<?php        
    $error = '';
    if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) 
    {
        $server = "localhost";
        $username= "";    // your username
        $pass = "";    // your password
        $dbname ="";   // your database name
        $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $pass, $dbname);
        if($conn -> connect_error){
            echo "Connection Failed!, " . $conn -> connect_error;

        if(checkValidation())
            // insert the data into the database and redirect to a new page.                     
    }

    function checkValidation()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
        if(empty($username))
        {
            $error = "Username field can't be empty";      
            return false;                    
        }
        if(empty($email))
        {
            $error = "Email field can't be empty";    
            return false;                      
        }
        if(empty($password))
        {
            $error = "Password can't be empty";                          
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($cpassword) || ($password != $cpassword))
        {
            $error = "Passwords don't match";                          
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
?>
```

Then add your html code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        form {
            border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            width: 19%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(5,25,9,0.2);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php>
    if(!empty($error))
    {
        echo "<p style='color: red;'></p>";
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Enter password again">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. put above your php file.

```
$server = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname ="";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $pass, $dbname);

if($conn -> connect_error){
    echo "Connection Failed!, " . $conn -> connect_error;
}
```